# How to find right formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to track payments made or owing in Excel but I cannot find a formlua or know how to use the right one.

I have a spread sheet that tracks people that paid a monthly due or is missing that due, also it allows them to pay ahead of time.

What I want to do is if they did not pay or did not pay ahead a time make a formula that says you allows me to see how much they owe. Is this possible?

More structure:

```
Name  jan  feb  mar  total paid  total owed
bla    5    5           10             5   -- i dont have this part figured out yet
```

Comment: We need to know a lot more about the structure of your spreadsheet.

Comment: @cooper of course it haves like a years worth of months and a lot more people but the people names'  should not be a issue i think

Comment: How do you know how much is owed monthly/initially? You need a base to start with imho. Also is it a fixed amount for every person each month or is it variable in some way?

Comment: It is a fix number 5 dollars a month for every month no inflation or anything

Comment: I am trying to put a formular like if cell is blank add 5 dollars just dont know how to do it with excel

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully the formatting of the answer is sufficient enough to answer your question.

You will also need to know what the start date is of payments for each person. That way you don't have to worry too much about doing lookups, range offsets, macros or user defined functions. Assuming the following headings are on the first row

```
A      B            C        D       E            F                G
Name   Start Date   Jan-11   Feb-11  Total Paid   #Payment Months  Total Owed
```

Your formula and values for the second row would then look like the following (Column and Row number provided):

```
A2: Bob
B2: Jan-2011
C2: 5
D2: 
E2: =SUM(C2:D2)
F2: =ABS(IF(DAY(B2)>=DAY(TODAY()),0,-1)+(YEAR(B2)-YEAR(TODAY())) *12+MONTH(B2)-MONTH(TODAY()))
G2: = (F5 * 5) - E5
```

The F2 formula is based off [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214134) to calculate the number of months elapsed from your start date. There are most likely other ways to do this but this just illustrates the point.

We can then multiply the number of months which have elapsed from the start date with the monthly rate and subtract the result from the total amount paid to date (G2).

The above should give the answer of Owed = 10. March would be included in the calculation even though it wasn't listed. Simply insert the columns for the months as needed and ensure the formula in E2 covers all the required cells. You can also replace the Today() function call in the F2 cell to point to another date if that suites your needs better. Also it would make sense to replace the magic number 5 in the G2 formula with some sort of constant such as MONTHLY_RATE perhaps.

Comment: So are you saying to put an actual day with the month and then ti should work.

Comment: What I am saying is that you can calculate the amount owed by calculating [Number of Months] * [Rate Per Month] - [Total Amount Paid]. The above just includes all the formulas to do that.

Comment: Thats awesome but this was started before me is there another way to do this much simpler im new to these type of formluas in excel? but  thanks alot